# Is it possible to make the trace of this matrix vanish?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Given a diagonal  $N \times N$ matrix $\mathbf X$ whose diagonal elements are $1-i$, let

$$\mathbf Y := \mathbf X\cdot \mathbf p\cdot \mathbf p^H\cdot \mathbf X^H$$

Is it possible to set the vector $\mathbf p$ of size $N \times 1$ to have $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf Y) = 0$,  where $\mathbf p \neq \mathbf 0$?

Comment: Thanks for changing the title. The context which makes this a signal processing question is still missing. Also, this feels extremely much like homework to me, so I can give you the answer right away: No, not possible, easy to show.. But can't give you an explanation without hearing what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: (hint: there is a case where this has a solution, but it's limited to the case where $\mathbf X$ is rank-deficient, and your question makes no mention of that)

Comment: In which case, could you please explain it?  The matrix $X$ is diagonal matrix whose  elements are $1-i$ @MarcusMüller

Comment: I explained it: in the rank-deficit case. Not doing your homework. This so far isn't even signal processing, and you've not given any context which I asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Rephrasing and generalizing, given matrix ${\rm A} \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, we would like to find vector ${\rm x} \in \Bbb C^n$ such that

$$0 = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm A} \, {\rm x} \, {\rm x}^* {\rm A}^* \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm x}^* {\rm A}^* {\rm A} \, {\rm x} \right) = {\rm x}^* {\rm A}^* {\rm A} \, {\rm x} = \| {\rm A} \, {\rm x} \|_2^2$$

where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the [Hermitian transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Does the notation $A^*$ mean the *complex-conjuage* or *Hermitian-transpose* of A? I think the latter, otherwise I cannot make sense of the dimensions of the matrices ?

Comment: @Fat32 Indeed, it is the Hermitian transpose. I updated my answer.

Comment: Wow interesting, in all of our (dsp) works we use $A^*$ to denote the conjugate of $A$ ,and  $A^T$ as the transpose of $A$, and $A^H = (A^*)^T$ as the Hermitian (a.k.a. conjugate-transpose) of the matrix $A$. What are the corresponding notations in yours?

Comment: @Fat32 I have no work in DSP. However, I have read papers in DSP using $*$ to denote the Hermitian transpose — some of Kailath's work, for example.

Comment: No I wondered the notation in mathematics, not dsp, the link you posted also uses $A^H$ as the Hermitian. Not big deal though.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  OK, thank you